# Is it possible to receive WM_TOUCH when window is transparent (WS_EX_TRANSPARENT)?

Tags: c++, winapi, touch

I want to use my app as fullscreen overlay to intercept touch point reported by my touch screen. So I set app window transparent and it's invisible, okay.

```
DWORD Flags1 = WS_EX_COMPOSITED | WS_EX_LAYERED | WS_EX_NOACTIVATE | WS_EX_TOPMOST | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT; // | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT; // | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT
DWORD Flags2 = WS_POPUP;

SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hWnd, NULL, 0, LWA_ALPHA);
```

But when window is transparent, no WM_TOUCH is received by cpp app.

How can I intercept touch points when app is transparent? Or can I delegate touch point "down" (to another app)?